# COOKIE. Почему не работают методы $APPLICATION->set_cookie() и $APPLICATION->get_cookie()

Tags: битрикс, cookie

Пытаюсь установить дополнительную куку пользователю, но кука не ставиться, проверил на другом сайте при тех же условиях, то все норм ставиться и читается. В чем может быть проблема ? 
Даже такой простой код не работает

```
<?require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

   $APPLICATION->set_cookie("USER_CITY","city");

echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_COOKIE);
echo "</pre>";
```

и в массиве с куками нет куки с нужным мне ключом, подскажите как можно решить этот трабл ?

и странно то, что еще и просто через  `<? setcookie('USER','asdas');?>` не ставиться кука, у сайта несколько алиасов, пока даже мыслей нет в чем может быть дело...

Comment: А пробовали её получить битрикс методом — $APPLICATION->get_cookie()?

Comment: да пробовал, результата нет никакого (

Comment: Код у Вас рабочий

Comment: http://mihanik71.ru/novaya-stranitsa.php разместил его. Всё работает

Comment: может какая нибудь ошибка при разработке сайта влиять на это? Просто да, я тоже размещал на других сайтах на битриксе и там все норм работает..

Answer (score 1):

Так значение этой куки получится только на втором хите. На текущем хите только дана команда установить ее. По факту, в браузере если посмотреть, она установилась?

Comment: это , да, после второй перезагрузки кука должна встать , но этого не происходит, т.е перед обновлением я комментирую строку с установкой куки и в массиве нечего нет.

Comment: Тогда ничего не понятно, как сказали выше, код рабочий. У меня отрабатывает

Comment: В $_COOKIE нет только этой куки или вообще пусто?

Comment: да, нет только нужной мне куки

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что работали на локальном хосте с адресом вида http://localhost:6449/. Надо поправить в настройках сайта - Доменное имя: оставить пустым, URL сервера (без http://):   localhost